# Getting Error While Trying to Enable Dialogflow Messenger

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

Facing error while I try to enable Dialogflow cx messenger, attaching screenshot for your reference on the actual error message.

[image]

I tried this in two different projects within same account. Below is the error message:

> "Invalid value at 'type' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v3alpha1.Integration.IntegrationType), "[INTEGRATIONS] START_INTEGRATION_START""

Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: Hi OP, I was able to reproduce your use case and there seems to be an unexpected behavior when enabling the Dialogflox CX messenger integration. I have created a PIT (Public Issue Tracker) regarding this in which you may also track through this link https://issuetracker.google.com/220673205

Comment: thanks , will check the status @ScottB

Answer (score 3):

Please try using the following workaround:

1. On the Dialogflow CX Agent page, go to "Manage" —> "Integrations".
2. Click "Connect" in the "Dialogflow Messenger" panel.
3. Choose the environment in the drop-down list to the left of the "Enable"
   button.
4. Open developer tools ([this is how to do this in different
   browsers](https://jeffrey1183.gitbooks.io/intro-to-programming/content/front-end-development/what-is-javascript/4developer-tools-on-different-browsers.html)).
5. Go to the "Network" section of the developer tools.
6. Click "Enable" button in the "Dialogflow Messenger" modal dialog box.
7. In the network log, find a request that has a name starting with
   "integrations:start" and status 400.
8. Right-click on the "integrations:start" request and select "Copy as cURL" item in the pop-up menu ("Copy" —> "Copy as cURL" in some browsers). If you're
   on Windows, you can select "Copy as PowerShell" instead.
9. Open a new window in the text editor of your choice and paste what you've just copied in the browser.
10. In one of the last lines, find and replace `[INTEGRATIONS] START_INTEGRATION_START` with `DIALOGFLOW_MESSENGER`.
11. Copy everything you have in the text editor window and paste it into the terminal — or PowerShell — command line.
12. Hit "Enter". You should see something like this:

```json
{
  "integration": {
    "name": "projects/foo-bar-1234/locations/global/agents/ab12cd34-ef56-7890-12ab-cd34ef567890/integrations/abcd1234-ef56-7890-ab12-cd345678fe90",
    "state": "ACTIVE",
    "dialogflowMessengerPayload": {},
    "type": "DIALOGFLOW_MESSENGER"
  }
}
```

13. Now, refresh the page in the browser.
14. Click "Connect" in the "Dialogflow Messenger" panel.
15. Copy the code in the dialog box and paste it into the source code of the webpage(s) where you'd like to have the Dialogflow Messenger widget.

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered same issue where i can see "Enable the unauthenticated API " button is disable, This is due to your project didn't link to any billing account, you can resolve this issue by just linking your project to billing account.

[image: You can see whether your project Billing is enabled or not][image: Here is how you can enable or Link project Billing]